# how to query from multiple table of mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a login system where i need to query from 2 sql table. The columns name are same in both table e.g - Email. The goal is if the value user entered is not found in first table it will look at the second table.is it possible by any chance?

Comment: It should be possible. Have you tried anything? Please post any attempt, the schema of the tables, example data and what data/columns you want to retrieve from the query. It's much easier to give a useful example and minimizes misunderstandings if we have something concrete to base it on.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have already tried so that others may help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```
SELECT table1.email AS table1_email, table2.email AS table2_email FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.email='whateveremail@gmail.com' OR table2.email='whateveremail@gmail.com'
```